# CSS max value limit for Number types variable properties

Tags: html, css, css-variables

I got this CSS code:

```
<style>
  div.indexCount {
    animation: counter 15s alternate ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    counter-reset: num var(--num);
  }

  div.indexCount::after {
    content: counter(num);
    display: none;
  }

  @property --num {
    syntax: '<number>';
  }

  @keyframes counter {
    from {
      --num: 0;
    }
    to {
      --num: 100000000000;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Which was supposed to allow me to have a nice counter animation from `0` to `100000000000`.

Instead, it is going from `0` to only `2147483647`.

Sounds to me like I've reached the limit of the `number` variable using CSS,  or am I not? I thought it was the limits of `Integers`, not `Number`. I can't find anything in the specifications - is there a way to circumvent that ?

EDIT: To the people saying it's a duplicate, I have another usage, it's not about `z-index`, but about a CSS variable property. I want to find a way to circumvent my issue, please do not tag it as a duplicate gain.

Comment: answer is here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#numbers

Comment: I read this page already @dippas. The max value is not defined.

Comment: From the answer linked  on duplicated question `So basically there are no limitations for z-index value in the CSS standard, but I guess most browsers limit it to signed 32-bit values (−2147483648 to +2147483647) in practice (64 would be a little off the top, and it doesn't make sense to use anything less than 32 bits these days)`, meaning the limit It's the maximum value of a 32 bits integer

Comment: I'm not talking about z-index, please help me in reopening my question. I am talking about CSS properties. Z-index is an integer, not a number. This question is not a duplicate. Even if it is limited, there must be a solution to my issue somewhere, no way people animating haven't found a workaround.

Comment: Browsers have limited values in CSS to max value of a 32 bits integer, simple as that.

Comment: @dippas A nitpick might add that we are talking about the limitations of a signed 32 bits int (-2147483647 to 2147483647) - compared to an unsigned 32 bits int (0 to 4 294 967 295)..

Answer (score 0):

The 'counter' has a limit of 2147483647, but the property can co much higher. The single limitation is the css style declaration you want to apply it to.

For example rotateZ() works for me with a 12 digit variable multiplied by 30 deg, but it might not work on other browsers.

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#numeric-ranges

> NOTE: At the time of writing, the bracketed range notation is new; thus in most CSS specifications any range limitations are described only in prose.